# get a subset of dataframe, where a given column value can be equal to 0 or 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `DF`, one column is named as 'check_sum', I need to get the subsection of dataframe where the `check_cum value equal to 0`  or `check_sum value equals to 1`.

I use the code

```
data_sub = DF[(DF['check_sum']==0]) or (DF['check_sum']==1])]
```

I get some error like this.  How to solve this kind of issue

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1440     @final
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1442         raise ValueError(
   1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.0.2/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing  Here is the official pandas documents showing how to do boolean indexing with `|` and `&` operators.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df.loc[((df['check_sum'].eq(0)) | df['check_sum'].eq(1))]
```